# Como usar método MeasureString?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o Seguinte código:

```
var font = new Font("Arial", 50);
var texto = "Meu texto";

var res = Graphics.MeasureString(texto, font); // Está linha não funciona.
```

Ao compilar o seguinte erro é gerado:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(string,
>   System.Drawing.Font)'

O que é preciso fazer para usar o `MeasureString`?

Comment: É windows forms?

Comment: Asp.Net MVC .Net Framework 4. Funciona será?

Comment: Não. Eu vou ver uma solução pra ti. Não esquece de colocar a tag `asp.net mvc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta criar o seguinte método:

```
private float GetWidthOfString(string str, Font font, int bitmapWidth, int bitmapHeight)
    {
        Bitmap objBitmap = default(Bitmap);
        Graphics objGraphics = default(Graphics);

        objBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
        objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);

        SizeF stringSize = objGraphics.MeasureString(str, font);

        objBitmap.Dispose();
        objGraphics.Dispose();
        return stringSize.Width;
    }
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12635970/4720858

Answer (score 1):

**Solução válida apenas para Windows Forms**

Se seu objetivo é obter um objeto `Size` com o tamanho da sua `string`, você pode usar o método `MeasureText` da classe `TextRenderer` dessa forma

```
var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText('Seu Texto Aqui', fonteDoTexto);
```